# How to set up and inject multiple PDO database connections in slim 4?

Tags: php, pdo, slim, php-di, slim-4

I could make an instance of `PDO` and inject it successfully. I defined the `PDO::class` directly and injected it in the constructor with `__construct(PDO $pdo)`. I would need something like `PDO1::class` and `PDO2::class` to inject it like follows: `__construct(PDO1 $pdo1, PDO2 $pdo2)` but that obviously doesn't work. There is only one `PDO` class and what I need to do is 2 instances of it with different database credentials.
What is the best way to do it?

I set up one definition of a database via PDO like this and it works:

File: `dependencies.php`

```php
use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

return function (ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
        PDO::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
            $dbSettings = $c->get('settings')['db1'];
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $dbSettings['host'] . ';dbname=' . $dbSettings['dbname'];
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            ];
            return new PDO($dsn, $dbSettings['user'], $dbSettings['pass'], $options);
        },
    ]);
};
```

File: `index.php`

```php
...
// Set up dependencies
$dependencies = require __DIR__ . '/../app/dependencies.php';
$dependencies($containerBuilder);
// Build PHP-DI Container instance
$container = $containerBuilder->build();
// Set container to create App with on AppFactory
AppFactory::setContainer($container);
// Instantiate the app
$app = AppFactory::create();
...
```

File `SomeRepository.php`

```php
use PDO;

class SomeRepository{

    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
}
```

I've seen something like this in [this](https://arjunphp.com/connect-multiple-database-slim-framework/) article:

```php
return function (ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
        'db1' => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
            $db1Settings = $c->get('settings')['db1'];
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $db1Settings['host'] . ';dbname=' . $db1Settings['dbname'];
            $options = [ ... ];
            return new PDO($dsn, $db1Settings['user'], $db1Settings['pass'],$options);
        },
        'db2' => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
            $db2Settings = $c->get('settings')['db2'];
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $db2Settings['host'] . ';dbname=' . $db2Settings['dbname'];
            $options = [ ... ];
            return new PDO($dsn, $db2Settings['user'], $db2Settings['pass'],$options);
        },

    ]);
};
```

But is it the best way to do it? And how can I access the connections in a repository class without having to inject the whole container?

Comment: Whats wrong with `__construct(PDO $pdo1, PDO $pdo2)` remember the `PDO` is a type hint, so hint that all the params are PDO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1. Extending PDO
2. Autowired objects

**1. Extending PDO**

```php
use PDO;

class PDO2 extends PDO
{
    // must be empty
}
```

The container definition:

```
use PDO2;

// ...

return [
    PDO::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
        return new PDO(...);
    },

    PDO2::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
        return new PDO2(...);
    },
];
```

**Usage**

```php
use PDO;
use PDO2;

class MyRepository
{
    private $pdo;

    private $pdo2;
    
    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, PDO2 $pdo2)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->pdo2 = $pdo2;
    }
}
```

**2. Autowired objects**

See Matthieu Napoli's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57758106/1461181

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple instances of a class in your app (here you have multiple instances of the `PDO` class), then you must configure which one to inject every time.

That means that `PDO` cannot be autowired, because PHP-DI cannot decide which instance you want depending on the service/controller/etc.

You need to use configuration (see http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html#autowired-objects) to define which instance (`db1` or `db2` in your example) to inject for each service.

```php
return [
    MyService::class => DI\autowire()
        ->constructorParameter('pdo', DI\get('db1'))
        ->constructorParameter('pdo2', DI\get('db2')),

    'db1' => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new PDO();
    },
    'db2' => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
        return new PDO();
    },
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you mind adding an example (definition and usage in service) which matches my code because I struggle a bit to understand what autowiring is and how I could implement it in my example?

Comment: @SamuelGfeller I have added an example.